# How to fix runtime overhead caused by newtype in array

Tags: rust, newtype

Rust claims the newtype pattern has no runtime overhead. However, I ran into cases where the statement seems not correct. Consider the following Rust program:

```rust
pub struct MyInt (i32);

pub fn f(xs: [i32; 3]) -> i32 {
    xs[0]
}

pub fn g() -> i32 {
    let xs = [MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3)];
    let myxs = xs.map(|x| x.0);
    f(myxs)
}
```

Given an API like the function `f`, which takes an array of `i32`, I have to map over my array of `MyInt` in order to call it. If I understand it correctly, this will create a new array, which seems not to be "runtime overhead free". Did I miss anything? Or is this considered as a misuse of the new type pattern?

I'd appreciate your help.

I didn't find much discussion on the topic of a newtype used in an array or other containers.

---

edit:

After reading the comments, I realized that the problem is more about array rather than the newtype. However, if I use the slice, to the best of my knowledge, I would need the following program

```
pub struct MyInt (i32);

pub fn f(xs: &[i32]) -> i32 { xs[0] }

pub fn g() -> i32 {
    let xs = [MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3)].as_slice();
    let myxs: &[i32] = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(xs) };
    f(myxs)
}
```

or with vectors

```
pub struct MyInt (i32);

pub fn f(xs: Vec<i32>) -> i32 { xs[0] }

pub fn g() -> i32 {
    let xs = vec![MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3)];
    let myxs: Vec<i32> = xs.into_iter().map(|MyInt(x)| x).collect();
    f(myxs)
}
```

However, it seems I can't get away with the unsafe `transmute` in the array version and I still have to pay for the cost of creating a new vector in the vector version. Are there any better approaches?

Comment: Technically the `map` has the overhead here, not the NewType.

Comment: This is not what rust considers "runtime overhead", because it is the work that you explicitly told it to do. The overhead comes from `map`, not `MyInt`. If you _really_ want this (although this wouldn't be my first solution), you could mark `MyInt` as `#[repr(transparent)]` and then you could safely `transmute` array of `MyInt`s to array of ints.

Comment: The compiler optimizes the `map()` to a `memcpy`: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/qWjMjrvEb. So yes, zero overhead.

Comment: .. The function signature is not well designed to work with your types, for zero-cost purpose.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman why is `memcpy` zero overhead?

Comment: It's the same overhead as if you just copy the array. The mapping of the newtype itself has zero ovehead.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Is there a way to avoid such `memcpy` but still use the newtype pattern here? Or is it just bad practice to use newtype in an array or any containers?

Comment: A copy will be generated anyway, since you're passing the argument to a function and that involves a copy. The compiler may optimize both copies, or one of them, or neither. If you can modify the function to take a slice, then yes, there is a way to avoid all copies.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks for you reply. I updated the question with my attempt using a slice or a vector. But neither looks good.

Comment: Zero overhead means the newtype doesn't do any indirection, and doesn't take more memory than `i32`. What you have here is a type problem: your function accepts an array (or slice) of `i32`, not of `MyInt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transmuting slices or `Vec` is only safe if the newtype is marked `#[repr(transparent)]` (or `#[repr(C)]`). If it is, you can use [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck) to do it safely:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, bytemuck::NoUninit)]
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct MyInt(i32);

pub fn f(xs: &[i32]) -> i32 { xs[0] }

pub fn slice() -> i32 {
    let xs = [MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3)];
    let myxs: &[i32] = bytemuck::cast_slice(&xs);
    f(myxs)
}

pub fn vec() -> i32 {
    let xs = vec![MyInt(1), MyInt(2), MyInt(3)];
    let myxs: Vec<i32> = bytemuck::cast_vec(xs);
    f(&myxs)
}
```

Comment: Is transmuting `Vec` _directly_ ever safe? My understanding is that `Vec<T>` and `Vec<U>` are not guaranteed to have the same layout even if `T` and `U` do. (There's the `into_raw_parts` + `from_raw_parts` method that is safe, of course.)

Comment: @cdhowie No, I meant `from_raw_parts()`.

Comment: I figured; the verbiage in the first sentence of your answer implies direct transmutation so I just wanted to clarify for other readers.